# How to use the Visual Studio 2012 command line tool from system()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am attempting to compile and run one visual C++ program (project1) from another visual C++ program (project2) using msbuild and other commands available in the Visual studio command line tool but not in the windows command line tool. Everything works fine if I run it in the visual studio command line tool. For example I can build using msbuild and it works just as I want it to. When I try to run the same command in my C++ program using system(), the system call appears to use the Windows command line and therefore cannot find any of the commands (msbuild in this example).  I am new to working with system() on windows (although I have extensive experience with it using Linux).  Is there some way to make my C++ program use the Visual Studio command line environment when I call system (rather than Windows command line environment)? 
Using the command window manually is not an option.  I need to compile and test a series of 200-300 different versions of the program in the project1.  This is why I am writing program2

Answer (score 1):

The key to getting Visual Studio to build from the command line is to set up the appropriate environment.  You might have several different VS versions installed, so you need a way of specifying which one to use.  Probably the easiest way of doing this is to have a level of indirection, where you generate a list of the commands to set up the required environment and write these to a batch file, then invoke `system()` to run that.

If you look in the `<visual studio>\vc\bin` directory then you'll find a file `vcvars32.bat`. This does a lot of the magic of setting up the environment for a particular toolset.  I think then that you could generate a batch file like this:

```
call path\to\visualstudio\vc\bin\vcvars32.bat

msbuild myproject
```

Note that you need the `call` syntax to call one batch file from another, otherwise it causes the shell to not return.

Answer (score 1):

1. Locate msbuild.exe by looking up the following registry key:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0\MSBuildToolsPath
2. Call PATH\msbuild.exe using the path from the registry key above

This approach doesn't require knowing the path to Visual Studio, and in fact it will work even if MSVS is not installed - [free] .NET SDK 4.0 is enough.

Here's an example code which will locate msbuild.exe and run it:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "winreg.h"

#define MAXSZ 1024
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HKEY key;
    TCHAR path[MAXSZ];
    DWORD dwSize = MAXSZ;
    long result;
    result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSBuild\\ToolsVersions\\4.0" ), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key);
    result = RegQueryValueEx(key, _T("MSBuildToolsPath"), 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)path, &dwSize);
    wcscat_s(path, MAXSZ, _T("msbuild.exe"));
    _wsystem(path);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using one of these?

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```